# How is there an apparent duplicate Primary Key in an identity PK column?

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is a labtrac database (dental software), hosted on-prem. The Order_Stage_Procedures table has a duplicate primary key, but there are some nuances. How is this possible, and what am I missing?

1. I found this while exporting data for analytics. The analytics engine found the duplicate.
2. When I search the table for the duplicate primary key, it does NOT return a duplicate value (only one).
3. When I filter the table on another column, I can physically see the duplicate in the returned results.

**Primary Key**

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order_Stage_Procedures] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Order_Stage_Procedures] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Ref] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Selecting from the table:**

```
SELECT [Ref]
      ,[OrderID]
      ,[StageID]
FROM [Labtrac].[dbo].[Order_Stage_Procedures]
  
where OrderID = --[REMOVED FOR PRIVACY]
and StageID = --[REMOVED FOR PRIVACY]

order by ref
```

[image: Snapshot showing duplicate results]

Adding a filter for the Ref with a duplicate does not show duplicates!?

```
SELECT [Ref]
      ,[OrderID]
      ,[StageID]
  FROM [Labtrac].[dbo].[Order_Stage_Procedures]

where OrderID = --[REMOVED FOR PRIVACY]
  and StageID = --[REMOVED FOR PRIVACY]
  and Ref = 2911187

order by ref
```

[image]

What am I missing!?

Comment: Could be a bug or a data corruption.  Take a backup. Rebuild the non-clustered indexes.  Check database integrity.  Upgrade to a supported version.

Comment: What is the `Ref` data type? What happens when you drop and re-add the PK constraint? If you `SELECT CAST(Ref AS VARBINARY(...))`, does it show the same value for both "duplicates"?

Comment: I know we're only *seeing* numbers, but I'm thinking there's either some kind of hidden whitespace character that your analytics engine doesn't respect or it's a collation situation. Follow mustaccio's advice above, and report back.

Comment: What is the exact data type of the column, including collation if it's a text type? Is the PK constraint actually enabled? Have you tried `DBCC CHECKTABLE (Order_Stage_Procedures) WITH EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS;`

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback. This is an integer column, so nothing related to hidden text or collation. I will try the varbinary and dbcc checktable suggestions.